# Frechet differentiable implies continuity in $\mathbb{R} ^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Need help completing a proof. The statement is as follows:

> Let $E \subset \mathbb{R} ^m$ be an open set. If  $f:E \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is Frechet differentiable at $a \in E$, then it is continuous at a.

*Proof*: Let $f:E \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ be Frechet differentiable. Then  for $a \in E$ ,   $\exists$  a linear map $A:\mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ s.t. $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta >0$, if $h \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $0<||h||<\delta$, then $$||f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah||<\epsilon||h||$$ We then have for $$||f(a+h)-f(a)||\leq||h||\frac{||f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah||}{||h||}+||Ah||$$ by the triangle inequality. But I get stuck here. I feel that I'm very close to finishing it but just cant see it. Any hints or help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the meaning of $\frac 1 h$ for $h \in \mathbb{R^m}$? And $f(a+h)$ is not well defined here since $a\ \in E \subset R^n$. Perhaps you mean $E \subset R^m$ ?

Comment: Sorry yes you are right $E \subset \mathbb{R^m}$. And the $\frac{1}{h}$ is suppose to be $\frac{1}{||h||}$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $a$, with derivative $A$.  Then we know that $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah\|}{\|h\|} = 0.$$  Define a function $\eta$ by $\eta(h) = {\|f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah\|}\big/{\|h\|} $ if $h\ne0$ and $\eta(0)=0$.  By the differentiability of $f$ at $a$ the function $\eta(h)$ is continuous at $h=0$.  (This is only a restatement of the differentiablilty of $f$, not a deep theorem.) So we know $$\tag{*}f(a+h) = f(a) + Ah +\|h\|\eta(h).$$ What we want is $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)=f(a)$.  But this can be read off of (*): the right hand side of (*) is  $f(a)$ plus terms that manifestly converge to $0$ as $h\to0$:  $Ah\to0$ as $h\to0$, and $\|h\|\to0$ and $\eta(h)\to0$ as $h\to 0$, and so does their product $\|h\|\eta(h)$, too, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to prove $\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h)-f(h)=0$ instead of using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ and
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h)-f(h)=\lim_{h\to 0} \|h\| \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Ah}{\|h\|}+Ah=0.
$$